# Sharepoint Infopath form read only after submitting

Tags: sharepoint

I have an infopath and deployed it to sharepoint document library. When i click on the add document in the library infopath form will open and user can fill the form and submit it. The form will be send for approval. But when any user clicks on the existing form present in the library then the form should not be in edit mode. User should not edit the form they should get only the read only form. How to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set hidden field with submit rules. Then in open form rules check this field and show read only view if field is checked.
But keep in mind - user can simply download form as xml, edit it in notepad and upload. You may set interface to read only, but if you don't set permissions on form items - user will can edit it.